# .Net C# Remote Method Invocation (RMI) (Client/Server communication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What exactly is **C#** version of **Java RMI**?

I want to invoke the methods of client from the server, ping the client from server etc.

How the server and client communication is done with c#?

Comment: Have a look at WCF, that's how client-server communication is often done in .Net.

Comment: Yes It more Efficent , Becuse instead the normal socket and client ,server application in rmi you get many usefull features to build your application .For example . RMI provides multithread server --the server is multithread by deafult so u don't need to add threading code. RMI support Object Serilization or Object Registery using a memory Address Just by Refernce and By Value Transfer of objects under the socket.But, I know only the JAVA RMI.

Comment: This question isn't about efficiency, it's asking for an identification of equivalent technology.

Comment: @GlenH7 lol ,what is an efficiency then compared to C# and JAVA

Comment: You are missing the point of the question.  It is not a C# vs. Java question.  It is asking for "I do XYZ in Java.  How do I do that in C#?"

Comment: Is there something native RMI in C# ? do u think that?

Comment: Please this repated question on stackoverflow and please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560107/what-is-the-net-standard-for-remote-method-invocation C# has no native RMI support as like of JAVA even they do ,since they require a lot library to do the stuff , i suggest you don't relay on C# ,since also RMI are some Time Platform Independent ,you should also think that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As svick said in his comment [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx) would be the technology in question.

Introduced in .NET 3.0, its goal was to pull together all manner of client-server communications, replacing various disparate methods (webservices, remoting, message queueing, etc.) with a single unified framework.